# How to search multiple files for textblocks and write those textblocks to another file

Tags: python, text, batch-file, grep

Here is an example of an input file:

```
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    HERE IS A LOT OF TEXT, THAT IS NOT INTERESTING 
    <br>
      <div id="text"><div id="text-interesting1">11/222-AA</div>
      <h2>This is the title</h2>

            <P>Here is some multiline desc-<br>
                 cription about what is <br><br>
                 going on here
      </div>

      <div id="text2"><div id="text-interesting2">IV-VI</div>
        <br>
        <h1> Some really interesting text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to grep multiple blocks of this file, like that between `<div id="text-interesting1">` and `</div>` then between `<P>` and `</div>` then between `<div id="text-interesting2">` and `</div>` and many more. The point is, there are multiple values that I want to retrieve.

I want to write those values to a file, e.g. comma separated. How can that be done?

From the example that Luke provided I made the following:

```
import os, re
path = 'C:/Temp/Folder1/allTexts'
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
    text = open(path + '/' + infile).read()
    match = re.search('<div id="text-interesting1">', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    start = match.end()
    end = re.search('</div>', text).start()
    print (text[start:end])


    match = re.search('<h2>', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    start = match.end()
    end = re.search('</h2>', text).start()
    print (text[start:end])


    match = re.search('<P>', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    start = match.end()
    end = re.search('</div>', text).start()
    print (text[start:end])


    match = re.search('<div id="text-interesting2">', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    start = match.end()
    end = re.search('</div>', text).start()
    print (text[start:end])


    match = re.search('<h1>', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    start = match.end()
    end = re.search('</h1>', text).start()
    print (text[start:end])

    print ('--------------------------------------')
```

Output is:

```
11/222-AA
This is the title


 Some really interesting text
--------------------------------------
22/4444-AA
22222 This is the title2


22222222222222222222222
--------------------------------------
33/4444-AA
3333 This is the title3


333333333333333333333333
--------------------------------------
```

Why does the

part not work?

Comment: I think you should maybe look at beautiful soup for this

Comment: You probably should use lxml or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: thank you! beautiful soup seems to be very good. have to read more on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
import os, re
path = 'C:/Temp/Folder1/allTexts'
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
    text = open(path + '/' + infile).read()
    match = re.search('<div id="text-interesting1">', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    start = match.start()
    end = re.search('<div id="text-interesting2">', text).start()
    print text[start:end]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, but have a look at the documentation for re: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html
In particular, you can use MatchObject.end() instead of start() if needed and there's also re.findall() if there are multiple blocks to extract from each file.

Comment: With some slight modifications it does a good job at the moment. Just have to figure out how to make multiple matches (but the order should be everytime the same). Thank you!

Comment: Accepted it, as it was really helpful for what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy is to parse the XML.  You will need to tidy your file up since strict XML requires matching tags, case consistency, etc.  Here is an example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys
tree = ElementTree.ElementTree()
tree.parse(StringIO(sys.stdin.read()))
print "All tags:"
for e in tree.getiterator():
    print e.tag
    print e.text
print "Only div:"
for i in tree.find("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body").findall("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div"):
    print i.text
```

Run on a slight modification of your file:

```
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
HERE IS A LOT OF TEXT, THAT IS NOT INTERESTING 
<br></br>
<div id="text"><div id="text-interesting1">11/222-AA</div>
  <h2>This is the title</h2>
  <p>Here is some multiline desc-<br></br>
      cription about what is <br></br><br></br>
    going on here</p>
</div>
  <div id="text-interesting2">IV-VI</div>
      <br></br>
    <h1> Some really interesting text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Example output,

```
> cat file.xml | ./tb.py 
All tags:
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html


{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}head


{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body

HERE IS A LOT OF TEXT, THAT IS NOT INTERESTING 

{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}br
None
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div
None
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div
11/222-AA
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}h2
This is the title
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}p
Here is some multiline desc-
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}br
None
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}br
None
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}br
None
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div
IV-VI
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}br
None
{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}h1
Some really interesting text
Only div:
None
IV-VI
```

But a lot of HTML is difficult to parse as strict XML, so this may prove hard to implement for your case.

Comment: Thank you! Think it is hard, as there are several hundred html files. At the moment I do not want to transform them to xml.